# Undefined reference to functions in Makefile.win

Tags: c++, makefile

I was working on a uni project recently. Everything was working fine, until I added some finishing touches to the code. When I try compiling I get:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x1f6): undefined reference to 'readline(std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string> >&, int)'

main.cpp:(.text+0x35d): undefined reference to 'readword(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >&, int)'
```

My project consists of 3 files: main.cpp, read.h and read.cpp. 
Here are the lines from makefile that the compiler seems to have a problem with:

```
$(BIN): $(OBJ)
$(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

main.o: main.cpp
$(CPP) -c main.cpp -o main.o $(CXXFLAGS)

read.o: read.cpp
$(CPP) -c read.cpp -o read.o $(CXXFLAGS)
```

I'd be grateful for any help given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably `read.cpp` contains the definitions of the two functions that your linker can't find. So you need both objects to build your binary:

```
$(BIN) : read.o main.o
    $(CPP) read.o main.o -o $(BIN)
```

Additionally, you can simplify your makefile with some common tricks. Since you're building all your object files the same, you can make that one rule:

```
# rule for all .o files depends their specific .cpp
%.o : %.cpp
    # here $< refers to the "%.cpp" dependency, and "$@" is the target
    $(CPP) -c $< -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS)
```

That will write both of your `main.o` and `read.o` rules. Then, we need to just tell make that that's what we want:

```
SRC = read.cpp main.cpp
OBJ = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SRC)) ## OBJ is "read.o main.o"

$(BIN) : $(OBJ) # depends on all the object files
     $(CPP) $(OBJ) -o $(BIN)
```

Now if you add, say, `write.cpp`, you only have to modify one line in your makefile instead of several. And then, you can avoid even doing that:

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp)
```

Comment: I'm sorry for being a newbie, but how am I supposed to put this in the makefile? Just add it to the end? And yes, read.cpp coontains the definitions of the functions.

Comment: Yep. Anywhere you want to put it is fine. Just make sure that the default target of the build is `$(BIN)` (or that you add it on the command line).

Comment: @eilchner I originally gave you an option that was wrong, not sure why I typed it, so I removed it. And threw in a bunch of other comments that should help you out.